# Is Betelgeuse's "scary" face ever revealed?

Tags: special-effects, beetlejuice

Has there ever been an in-universe *or* behind the scenes reveal of what Betelgeuse's "Can you be scary?" face looks like?

[image: Beetlejuice scary face]

The animatronics rig is cool, but it seems to only consist of the portions the audience can see during the gag:

[image: The animatronic]

So that seems like something that refutes the idea of a scrapped "full version" lurking out there somewhere, but who knows?

I haven't seen enough of the animated series to know if he ever replicates the trick on the show, but I'd consider an appearance there as canon as well.

Arguably, not knowing is better, so I'm thinking this is by design, but I'd love to see it anyway, because clearly I don't know what I want.

Comment: Personally I hope not. The whole reason the gag works is that it's left to the audience's imagination. Some things are better left unseen...

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish I'm with you, actually. There's no way it holds up to whatever we've conjured in our minds, but I just can't help myself.

Comment: There's nothing in the Art of Tim Burton books that I can see, nor in any of the official comic-book releases.